# Javascript convert a Blob object to a string and back

Tags: javascript, blob

I have to send a Blob as a String and convert it back to an Blob. The method blob.text() returns a promise with it's content as a String. But how can i convert this string back to a blob? I want to convert it into an image data url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To convert a string to a blob, you use the `new Blob` interface:

```js
const blob = new Blob([string], {
  type: 'image/jpeg' // or whatever your Content-Type is
});
```

See [this section of the document you linked to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#creating_a_blob).

If you have a `Blob` object called `blob`, `blob.type` will give its content type.  So you could deconstruct and reconstruct it as follows:

```js
const string = await blob.text();
const type = blob.type;
const blob2 = new Blob([string], {type: type});
```

Comment: Excellent! Way simpler than using `FileReader`, as suggested by most google results.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for images in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const base64Data = "dGVRAXXRoZXIUl";
```

Depending on the format of the base64 string, you might need to prepend content type data. For example, a JPEG image

```js
const base64Return = await fetch(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Data}`);
```

Then, convert the response to a blob

```js
const blob = await base64Return.blob();
```

For "text/html" format, for example, you can get the raw text

```js
const text = await base64Return.text();
```

Comment: fetch argument should be quoted - fetch("data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Data}")

Comment: should i use the return value of blob.text() as base64Data?